# Installing WixToolset 3 on Visual studio 2019 NestedExtensionInstallException

Tags: visual-studio, wix, wix3

While installing WixToolset 3 extention (with offline installation) on VisualStudio Enterprise 2019 I'm getting the following exception on the instllation log:

Install Error : Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.NestedExtensionInstallException: The extension 'WixToolset.VisualStudioExtension.Schemas3' nested within 'WixToolset.VisualStudioExtension.Dev16' failed to install.
Exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.MissingPackagePartException' was thrown. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.MissingPackagePartException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.MissingPackagePartException' was thrown.

I don't understand which part is creating the MissingPackagePartException, help is needed .

TNX

I have already tried to add security certificates and to remove + re-install WixToolset & Visual Studio 2019.
Without any success...

Comment: There is a very similar question here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vsix-2019-extension-fails-to-install/939006  Could you check the WiX installation log? You might need to uninstall WiX, then manually delete a folder such as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX`, then re-install.